# How to pass a boolean value between Angular components for switching display of a style

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, eventemitter

I have this form that is almost ready. Now I only have to make a modal window with content and it should pop open with click on a button which is inside of a child component. Modal, on the other hand, is a part of a parent component. I need to communicate them with each other in order to inform the parent, that the button was clicked and that now it's time to open a modal. 
I emit a boolean event, which is equal to the state of a clicked button, but I don't get any reaction from the parent, although I have a property bindable from outside (`@Input()`)
How can I achieve such a task? Where am I mistaken?

Child component method

```
  onReset() {
    this.formResetClicked = !this.formResetClicked;

    this.formReseted.emit(this.formResetClicked); }
```

Parent's HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
        <app-form-slider class="slider-app"></app-form-slider>
    </div>
    <div class="form" (formReseted)="clickedState = $event">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="modal" [ngStyle]="{display: clickedState ? 'block' : 'none'}">
      <div class="modal__content">
        <div class="modal__content--header">
          <span>&times;</span>
          <p>WARNING!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__content--text">
          <p>If you click 'continue' the all information will be deleted. <br>Close this window if you don't want this to happen.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__content--button">
          <button>Continue</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Property of a parrent

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AwesomeFormTask';

  @Input() clickedState: boolean;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not need to use **`@Input()`**. 
You can call child component to parent component using **`@Output()`** and **`EventEmitter`** as follows.

**child.component.ts**

```
@Output() formReseted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

formResetClicked: boolean = false;

onReset() {
   this.formResetClicked = !this.formResetClicked;
   this.formReseted.emit(this.formResetClicked); 
}
```

Listen to **`formReseted`** **`event`** from the parent as follows.

**parent.component.html**

```
<child (formReseted)="testShowHide($event)"></child>

<p *ngIf="show">Showing the Modal</p>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
show: boolean = false;

  testShowHide(show) {
    this.show = show;
  }
```

**[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-59180308?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks, that does it for me!

Comment: Okay, yeah, no. I did it in my project exactly how you pointed out I should and it doesn't work. You see, I don't have a child component tag in my HTML of a parrent, I have a router outlet. Should I put an event binding attribute on a <router-outlet>, or on a div that contains it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with how you handled the event. `@Input` will create a bindable property on the component selector. So don't use `@Input`.

Like the following

childComponent.ts

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() formReseted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  formResetClicked = false;
  public onReset() {
    this.formResetClicked = !this.formResetClicked;
    this.formReseted.emit(this.formResetClicked);
  }
}
```

parentComponent.html

```
<app-child (formReseted)="onFormReset($event)"></app-child>
```

parentComponent.ts

```
onFormReset(isFormResetClicked) {
   console.log(isFormResetClicked)
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-output-example?embed=1&file=src/app/child/child.component.ts)

Comment: I don't quite get how all this works, but isn't @Input suppose to get the information from outside?